# How to compare two arrays and find the indices where the elements differ?

Tags: scala

Is there any builtin function in Scala (not able to fetch indexes after comparing)?

Here is some JavaScript code I already have:

```
var diffIndexes = [];
var newTags = ['a','b','c'];
var oldTags = ['c'];
var diffValues = arrayDiff(newTags, oldTags);
console.log(diffIndexes); // [0, 1]
console.log(diffValues); // ['a', 'b'] "
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of the JS snippet in your question?

Comment: The posted code makes no sense. How does `diffIndexes` get populated? What's the expected result if `newTags = ['a','b']` and `oldTags = ['c','d']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it really easy using [`zipWithIndex`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableOnceOps.html#zipWithIndex:CC%5B(A@scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance,Int)%5D), and [`unzip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#unzip%5BA1,A2%5D(implicitasPair:A=%3E(A1,A2)):(CC%5BA1%5D,CC%5BA2%5D))

```
val (diffValues, diffIndexes) = newTags.zipWithIndex.filter(c => !oldTags.contains(c._1)).unzip
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YCo7M3CCTwqbT2qBDP5tcw)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as follows:

```
def arrayDiff[T](newTags: List[T], oldTags: List[T]) = {
  oldTags.foldLeft(newTags.zipWithIndex.toMap) {
    case (seed, char) => {
      seed.get(char) match {
        case Some(_) => seed - char
        case _ => seed
      }
    }
  }
}


val newTags = List('a', 'b', 'c')
val oldTags = List('c')
val (diffIndexes, diffValues) = arrayDiff(newTags, oldTags).unzip
println(diffIndexes) // List(a, b)
println(diffValues) // List(0, 1)
```

I'm not sure if that what you meant, since what you want to do when `oldTags` has some values that `newTags` not?, In my case scenario - its will ignore the oldTag since its not in the newTags